# yum remove does not work for erlang*

Tags: erlang, rpm, yum

I installed erlang with

`wget http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm`

`rpm -Uvh erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm`

`sudo yum install erlang`

Now I wanted to remove it, I run `yum remove erlang*` - this didn't work. The output message is:

```
[ec2-user@ip-111-11-11-11 ~]$ sudo yum remove elrang*
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No Match for argument: elrang*
No Packages marked for removal
```

Why cannot I remove erlang the same way I installed it? How can I remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two reasons:

- one (mentioned by @byaruhaf) is that your example command for removal has a typographical error.
- the other is that in both cases, you are using a shell command which globs (matches via wildcard) the actual rpm filename.  But `yum` expects its argument to be a ***package***  (not a ***filename***).

For whatever reason, `yum` accepts a filename for installing, but not for removing (checked with CentOS6).